# Bluetooth connection failed from Raspberry Pi at LE Read Remote Used Features

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

I'm trying to pair a Raspberry Pi 4 model B with an [Ortho remote](https://teenage.engineering/store/ortho-remote/), but it's failing to connect.

I'm using the Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+ kernel

I'm still very new to debugging bluetooth, but it looks like it's failing at the "LE Read Remote Used Features" step, with an "Connection Failed to be Established (0x3e)" error. What does this mean? Anything I can do to debug this further?

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# trust F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Changing F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to connect to F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: no
[bluetooth]# pair F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to pair with F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
[CHG] Device F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: no


$ sudo btmon
...
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 44                                                                                                          {0x0002} [hci0] 1979.845117
        LE Address: F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 31
        Name (complete): ortho remote
        Flags: 0x04
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: not assigned (1104)
          Data: 01005238434b4931324b
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                                                                                            #1688 [hci0] 1979.845351
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                                                   #1689 [hci0] 1979.846487
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14                                                                                                                #1690 [hci0] 1979.846501
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                    ..........
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                                                                   #1691 [hci0] 1980.142018
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Connection Failed to be Established (0x3e)
        Handle: 64
        Features: 0x3f 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Connection Parameter Request Procedure
          Extended Reject Indication
          Slave-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
          Unknown features (0x0000000008000000)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10                                                                                                          {0x0001} [hci0] 1980.142093
      Pair Device (0x0019) plen 7
        Status: Failed (0x03)
        LE Address: F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Static)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                                                              #1692 [hci0] 1980.143150
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Reason: Connection Failed to be Established (0x3e)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                                                        {0x0001} [hci0] 1980.143206
        LE Address: F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Static)
        Reason: Unspecified (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                                                        {0x0002} [hci0] 1980.143206
        LE Address: F9:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Static)
        Reason: Unspecified (0x00)
```

Comment: Check my answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68202067/bluez-cant-connect-permanently-to-a-bluetooth-le-remote-function-not-implement/68301095#68301095).

Comment: Can you also share the spreadsheet of the device? The website is very badly designed.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mr.Panda, it looks like setting ControllerMode = dual did the trick.  Would you like to write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I would guess this is due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63813446/556495, but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like for some reason your Bluetooth mode was set to `bredr`, and because your device is a **BLE** device that does not support **Bluetooth Classic** -> `BR/EDR Not Supported`, you were not able to connect. Thus, setting it to `dual` does the trick. You can set it to `dual` mode via editing `etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. I would expect a same behaviour, if you set it to `le` as well.

```
# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
ControllerMode = dual
```