# Unknown device flag in Device Connected event

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm trying to connect to a BLE device with BlueZ and standard tools like `gatttool`, and monitoring the results with `btmon`.

Everything worked until yesterday, when one device started to fail. During connection, btmon creates this log:

```
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25
...
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 5
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 31
      LE Enhanced Connection Complete (0x0a)
        Status: Success (0x00)
...
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 20
        LE Address: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF (XYZ)
        Flags: 0x00000008
          **Unknown device flag (0x00000008)**
        Data length: 7
        Flags: 0x06
```

What is that "Unknown device flag"?

Is it causing the device to be immediately disconnected?

Here is the complete btmon log with colors:

[image]

As you can see, in less than 1 second, the device is considered disconnected. It seems like something is really preventing this connection and I can't figure out what is it.

Comment: `Unknown device flag` is printed when there is a flag that is not known by btmon https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/monitor/packet.c#L12719 . What version of BlueZ are you using? If I skip back a few versions then bit 3 (hex 08) doesn't have a setting. https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/808be93a11a54074aba901718d37aacaaa292356/monitor/packet.c#L12047-L12052. Not sure why you are suddenly getting the issue. Did the firmware get updated on the device?

Comment: gatttool were [deprecated by the BlueZ project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) in 2017. `bluetoothctl` is the supported command line tool for scanning and connecting to devices.

Comment: Don't focus too much on that flag, I would say. Instead try to focus on the issue "Connection failed to be established". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63813446/556495 for a list of reasons for that error to occur.

Answer (score 0):

just wipe previous data first from emmulator by clicking on three dots then click on wipe data.